# Be Notified of Multiple ObservableObject Property Changes in Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a Swift Combine question. Let’s say I have an `ObservableObject` with a few properties like this:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = AppState()
  @Published var a: Object?
  @Published var b: Object?
  @Published var c = [Object]()
}
```

I know I can be notified if a single object changes like this:

```
myCancellable = AppState.shared.$a.sink { a in
  //Object 'a' changed
}
```

But is there a way to watch multiple properties and respond if any of them change?

Something like:

```
myCancellable = AppState.shared.[$a, $b, $c].sink { a, b, c in
  //Objects 'a', 'b', or 'c' changed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `a`, `b`, and `c` are the same type (which Asperi pointed out to me they are not in the example, since `c` is an array), you can use `Publishers.MergeMany`:

```
myCancellable = Publishers.MergeMany([$a,$b,$c]).sink { newValue in 

}
```

There are also more specific versions of this function for a set number of arguments. For example, in your case, you could use `Publishers.Merge3`

Often, in examples I've seen online, you'll see `Publishers.MergeMany` followed by `collect()`, which gathers results from all of the publishers before moving on, publishing the results as an array. From your question, though, it doesn't sound like this will meet your needs, as you want a notification each time a singular member changes.

Comment: MergeMany is for one type, but `c` is an array in topic starter question, so this won't compile.

Comment: Ah -- good point. Missed that detail. Edited post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The possible variant is to observe any published changes of entire object, like

```
myCancellable = AppState.shared
    .objectWillChange.sink {
       // react here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great answers. Another idea I stumbled across was to just store my objects in a `struct` and observe that.

```
struct Stuff{
  var a: Object?
  var b: Object?
  var c = [Object]()
}
```

Then in my `AppState` class:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = AppState()

  @Published var stuff: Stuff!
}
```

Then in the publisher:

```
myCancellable = AppState.shared.$stuff.sink { stuff in
  print(stuff.a)
  print(stuff.b)
  print(stuff.c)
}
```

I like this approach since I don't want to observe everything that might change in the `AppState` class (which is probably an indication I should break it into smaller pieces). This seems to be working well so far.